# Inserting into table in order

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I insert values into a table (MySQL) in the following manner:
On all the rows of a table, in order of ID column (PK), insert incrementing number in column 'num'?
For example if the table had 3 rows , with Ids 1,5,2, I want ID 1 to get num=1, ID 2 to get num=2 and ID 5 to get num=3.

**EDIT**
I will explain why I (think I) need this:
I am trying to split a column off a table into a separate table with a 1-to-1 relation. I thought I would get all the values in order of ID and insert them into the new table, with an auto-incrementing PK. then I know that, in order of ID, the values for the new reference column in the original table will be auto-incrementing numbers. So I want to insert them in that order. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Might I ask why you want to do this?  MySQL will allow you to sort the data by whatever column you want after it's already in the table.  What happens if you later insert a 3 or a 4?  Are you planning on reordering your entire table again?

Comment: Also, SQL operates on sets and does not know about order per se.

Comment: @knittl - Which is why when inserting into a table with an autoincrement field, you can specify an `ORDER BY` clause...

Comment: The values in the auto_increment column will automatically be in the order you insert the rows in. If below answers or this doesn't answer your question, please explain how you're inserting the rows.

Comment: @baruch: The expression "insert values" is not exact. One inserts rows, not values. What you want actually (if I understand correctly) is to update some rows, not insert new ones.

Comment: @SenorAmor I hope my edit explains this.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I hope my edit explains my need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer. It is very simple:

```
SET @c=0;
UPDATE myTable SET num = (@c:=@c+1) ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 4):

i am currently not in front of sql database engine and cannot therefore submit fully verified sql code. however if your num field is not an autoincrement field than do something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_x (
    num int auto_increment primary key,
    reference_id int
);

INSERT temp_table_x (reference_id)
SELECT id FROM source_table ORDER BY id;

UPDATE source_table st 
    SET st.num = x.num
FROM temp_table_x x
WHERE reference_id = id;
```

Comment: Surely you need and ORDER BY on the INSERT statement?

Comment: as baruch statet id in his source table is a pk, an order by is not necessary

Comment: @JulienMay if you specify no ORDER BY there is no certainty that the order the rows will be returned in will be what you expect as it's the order which MySQL has them stored.  By specifying the ORDER BY you are 100% certain that the order they are returned in is the order you intend regardless of insertion order.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net - Agreed.  The chances are that you get the right order without the clause, but without the ORDER BY there is absolutely no ***guarantee***.  And as this is about creating a guaranteed sequence, it seems pretty important to include it.

Comment: Also agreed... even if its a clustered index, it is not guaranteed that the sql engine takes that index for sorting. Just added the order clause in my answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the `num` field is an autoincrement field it should be as simple as:

```
INSERT INTO
  yourTable (
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    etc
  )
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  field3
FROM
  yourSourceTable
ORDER BY
  originalIdField
```

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear, but I am adding the column 'num' to an existing table, not adding rows.

Answer (score 1):

I would NOT make a field that references a column in another table an auto-increment column.

Even if the column that it references is an auto-increment, I wouldn't make the column auto-increment. It will be difficult to keep the columns in sync. If an insert is rolled back in one table but not the other, you'll be out of sync until you reset the auto_increment value.

If it's a 1 to 1 relationship, feel free to make the column a primary key. That way it will be ordered by the column, and it will ensure unique values. However, if any two columns must match, they should not both be auto-increment, though, they should be of the same type (eg. INTEGER).

For example, here's our original table, where the first column is an auto-increment integer column:

```
id  customer_name  email_address
---------------------------
1   jsmith         jsmith@aol.com
2   bwilliams      bwilliams@aol.com
```

If you wanted to split the email_address off to its own table, in a 1 to 1 relationship:

```
id  email_address
---------------------------
1   jsmith@aol.com
2   bwilliams@aol.com
```

I would make the first column an integer field and make it the primary key, but it would NOT be an auto-increment column.

To insert values into such a table, you could simply do this:

```
INSERT INTO table2
  (id, email_address)
SELECT id, email_address
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY id
```